# How to name generic input value types?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

We have an app in which user needs to specify some parameters and their value types.

GUI example:

```
Parameter details

Name
[              ] *text field

Type
[              ] *combobox
```

Here's a list of allowed parameter value types in our app (though I believe it's pretty generic):

- single ordinal or floating-point value
- datetime value
- list of options from which you can choose only one
- list of options from which you can choose many
- text input
- boolean input

What is the correct way of naming these types in a combobox/radiogroup from which user selects parameter value type? So that it is clear which option is selected, but is not overly wordy (since GUI space is valuable).

I guess that would be (correspondingly): Numeric/Digital?, Datetime?, Single-choice list, Multi-choice list, Text, Flag?

Please reply with which parameter value type names should be used to be proper English?

---

To address comments, I'm looking specifically for proper English words choice, not the UI/UX/programming advice.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Does "input values types" and "parameter names" mean variable names or input field labels? Perhaps this question would be better asked on stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @Mick thanks for your comment, I've tried to clarify the question. I need a caption for the combobox from which user will select value type. The question is specifically about proper english (meaning user interaction), not about programming.

Comment: @Kromster: user experience design is a better fit for [ux.SE] than ELL.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I would agree, if it was about UI layout or UX design. Here it is mostly about Engish word choice.

Comment: Trying to simplify - are you looking for *plain English* definitions of the 'types' in that bulleted list?

Comment: @Astralbee exactly so )

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possibilities:

- single ordinal or floating-point value - *Numeric value* or *number*
- datetime value - *date* or *date and time*
- list of options from which you can choose only one - *single choice list* (as you suggested, I can't think of anything better)
- list of options from which you can choose many - *multi-choice list* but beware that the term "multiple choice" refers to any question with a list of options, not necessarily where you can choose just more than one.
- text input - *Free text*
- boolean input - *true/false* or *yes/no* denoted as 1 or 0